# Is there a free data analyzer for helping in information visualization?

Tags: database, linux, data-analysis, information-visualization

I prepared a questionaire for evaluating a software and submitted it to n people. 
The questionaire has many questions, all with a single choice, like following:

1. What's your age?  (13-15) (19-25) (26-35) (over 35)
2. What's your qualification? (college student) (graduated) (phD)

....
Express an opinion with a rateing from 1 to 4 on the following aspects:
 a1
 a2
  ...
I copied all answer both in Excel and in a Mysql Database and now I need to found correlations between eg. age and ratings for each aspect valued.
Is there a free tool to do this for Linux, that can help me visualizing correlations? Eg. most people between 13 and 18 evalued aspect1 bad, 19-25 quite bad, 26-35 quite good...

I know many types of visualizations for bivariate, trivariate data (eg. scatterplots) but I don't know how to obtain them.

Excuse me for my worst english, I hope you have understood my issue... thanks in advance!

Comment: I have seen online tools for that, but don't have any links handy. Might be worth spending an hour or two on Google, though.

Comment: I found Mondrian, there are several models for information visualization (scatterplot, parallel coordinates plots, ...). Charts are quite ugly, but better than nothing... 
If someone can suggest something better... :-)

Answer (score 0):

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) has built in features to make graphs from tables, like you can do in Excel. Try using that :)

See http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Inserting_Charts and the links on that page for more help.

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried LibreOffice, but it has just few trivial solutions, nothing to test correlation between multivariate data :(
I found a Mondrian, it has what I was looking for, but charts are quite ugly :P

Answer (score 0):

[R](http://www.r-project.org/) is a top-drawer statistical program, but I'm not confident that's quite what you're looking for.